# do cancer cells respond to EM fields?

Tags: cancer

Do cancer cells respond to electromagnetic fields? If so, can someone please provide reliable information as to how they behave in such fields? Do you suppose the growth rate to be affected in any way ?

Comment: I guess you are talking about low energetic EM fields, right? Do you have any special treatment in mind?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind(s) of cancer you are interested in? Cancer is not one thing at the cellular level. Cancers come in all types.

Comment: @Chris, if cancer cells are basically due to uncontrolled growth, we can try to control them using different frequencies and intensities of EM fields. After all, neural signals are electromagnetic in nature. If those EM signals can control the body and its growth, maybe we can use some to inhibit growth as well.

Comment: @kmm, suppose i take a lump of gastric cancer cells and expose them to EM fields(variable or constant). Will any significant effect be observed?

Comment: Most likely not. There is an approved therapy for brain tumors called tumor therapy fields, but there is little (if any) proof, that this works. Additionally, neural signals are a little bit more complicated than just being a field.